# Twitter stream using OAuth in Python behaving differently on two equally configured machines

Tags: python, twitter, urllib2, twitter-oauth, http-status-code-401

I have the **same** piece of coding to deal with Twitter User Stream running on **two** different machines. Both machines are Ubuntu Lucid using python 2.6.5, but on the machine in my home I receive `HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized` while on the university it works perfectly. On both machines it works perfectly when I use curl with the same parameters, i.e., consumer key, consumer secret, acces token, and access key.

See the code bellow, it was created by [Josh Sharp](http://www.joshsharp.com.au/blog/view/twitter-user-streams-with-python)

```
from oauth.oauth import OAuthRequest, OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1
from hashlib import md5
import json, time
import random, math, re, urllib, urllib2

STREAM_URL = "https://userstream.twitter.com/2/user.json"

class Token(object):
    def __init__(self,key,secret):
        self.key = key
        self.secret = secret

    def _generate_nonce(self):
        random_number = ''.join(str(random.randint(0, 9)) for i in range(40))
        m = md5(str(time.time()) + str(random_number))
        return m.hexdigest() 

CONSUMER_KEY = 'consumer_key'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'consumer_secret'
ACCESS_TOKEN = 'token'
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = 'token_secret'

access_token = Token(ACCESS_TOKEN,ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
consumer = Token(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET)

parameters = {
    'oauth_consumer_key': CONSUMER_KEY,
    'oauth_token': access_token.key,
    'oauth_signature_method': 'HMAC-SHA1',
    'oauth_timestamp': str(int(time.time())),
    'oauth_nonce': access_token._generate_nonce(),
    'oauth_version': '1.0',
}


oauth_request = OAuthRequest.from_token_and_callback(access_token,
                http_url=STREAM_URL, 
                parameters=parameters)
signature_method = OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1()
signature = signature_method.build_signature(oauth_request, consumer, access_token)

parameters['oauth_signature'] = signature

data = urllib.urlencode(parameters)

req = urllib2.urlopen("%s?%s" % (STREAM_URL,data))
buffer = ''


# We're using urllib2 to avoid external dependencies
# even though pyCurl actually handles the callbacks
# much more gracefully than this clumsy method.
# We read a byte at a time until we find a newline
# which indicates the end of a chunk.

while True:

    chunk = req.read(1)
    if not chunk:
        print buffer
        break

    chunk = unicode(chunk)
    buffer += chunk

    tweets = buffer.split("\n",1)
    if len(tweets) > 1:
        print tweets[0]
        buffer = tweets[1]
```

The error when I try to execute in home is:

```
File "py_stream.py", line 48, in <module>
req = urllib2.urlopen("%s?%s" % (STREAM_URL,data))
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
  return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 397, in open
  response = meth(req, response)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 510, in http_response
  'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 435, in error
  return self._call_chain(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
  result = func(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 518, in http_error_default
  raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
```

Since it works using curl on both machines, I suppose nothing is wrong related with the SSL certification. But at the same time it makes me wonder what fails when I use it in home.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After many weeks trying to find what was the problem, I discovered that the clock was not well synced with the one responsible for the Twitter Stream. And therefore, Twitter returns 401: Unauthorized.

If you are using Ubuntu, you can solve this problem using ntpdate as following:

```
sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com
```